# How do I validate column from a table

Tags: php, mysql

How do I validate column from a table 
The answer will be yes or no

```
pica--> gallery -->
pic1             pic2                pic3        pic4       password_del
picture1.jpg picture2.jpg    picture3.jpg    picture4.jpg     1234567890
```

I'm trying to get

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user_name","password","pica");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM gallery WHERE id = 1 AND password_del = '1234567890";
$rs= $mysqli->query($sql); 
if ($rs > 0){
echo "find";
}
else{
echo 'not find';
}
```

I do not get any notification if password exists or not
What's wrong?

Comment: Your Query is invalid. After the Password you need an **'**. Print out errors: http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I don't find column `id` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using mysqli object oriented with procedural way. If you want to use $mysql object then you have to connect by this syntax

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Answer to your question

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user_name","password","pica");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as counter FROM gallery WHERE id = 1 AND password_del = '1234567890' ";

$rs= mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$row_count= $rows['counter'];

if (($row_count) > 0){
  echo "found";
}   
else{
  echo 'not found';
}
```

Comment: Its depend on your data And what you want then ? @user3397906

Comment: If he does not find anything
Why is not an answer "not found"

Comment: If user exists with id = 1 and password_del = '1234567890' then it will always show found, And it should be. So what's your problem ?

Comment: If user exists with id = 1 and password_del = '1234567890' is show You have an error in your SQL syntax

Comment: @user3397906    "  If user exists with id = 1 and password_del = '1234567890' "  ... it was not a query or sql but it was comment . You put it in sql query ? 
it must be error in sql query. In screenshot you are not using my code ? So ...

Comment: Then check this answer as accepted . Click on a check box left of my answer to check as accepted  @user3397906

Answer (score -1):

Correct your Query by adding ' at the end before inverted Comma.

```
$mysqli= new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 $sql = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM gallery WHERE id = 1 AND password_del = '1234567890'";
$rs =   $mysqli->query($sql);
$num_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$row_cnt = $num_row['count'];
if (($row_cnt) > 0){
echo "find";
}
else{
echo 'not find';
}
```

[Reference](http://pk1.php.net/mysqli_num_rows)

Comment: I get Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\update.php

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in